# Using Derby SQL to calculate value for histogram

Tags: sql, derby

I have a table with various SKU in totes.

The table is `totecontents` with below columns:

- ToteID
- SKU

Each Tote can contain a maximum of 6 SKUs. (programmatically constrained)

```
select toteid, count(*) as qtypertote

from totecontents 

group by toteid;
```

gives me a list of totes with the number of skus in each.

I now want to get to a table with following result

SkuCount Occurences where each row would have the ordinal value (1 through 6 ) and then the number of occurences of that value.

My efforts included the following approach

```
select count(*) 
from 
      ( select toteid, count(*) as qtypertote 
        from totecontents 
        group by toteid)
group by qtypertote;
```

Comment: You need to edit your question, show the complete table DDL, sample data as a table, expected output as a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stung by the comments I performed more research. This works:

```
SELECT CountOfskus, COUNT(1) groupedCount

FROM

( SELECT COUNT(*) as countofskus, toteid

  FROM totecontents

  Group By toteid 

) MyTable

GROUP BY countofskus;
```